# HP Pavilion Slimline s3220n SD Card Reader Issue

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure, troubleshooting, hp-pavilion, micro-sd-card

I have an HP Pavilion Slimline running Windows 7. It came with an SD card reader. I can read SD cards with it, but when I plug in a Micro SD card via an adapter, it is not recognized.

The light turns on by the reader as if it can see that I've inserted the card, but the card does not show up in Windows. Micro SD cards used to work in this reader and work in my laptop readers, so I know the card itself is not an issue. I have also tried with multiple adapters without any luck.

Comment: Have you successfully user _this_ SD card with _this_ PC before?

Comment: Is it an SDHC card?

Comment: Perhaps adding more information, like the exact models of computer and SD card would be helpful? Because it would be...

Comment: The light could be triggered by something as small as a physical mechanism being pressed when a card is physically inserted all the way into the reader. Is your card recognized by your laptop?

Comment: I suspect your MicroSD card is of a higher class than the capability of the adapter or card reader.

Comment: You said the card *used* to work in other laptops, but does it *still* work in other laptops?  If the card was reformatted, Windows may not assign a drive letter if the file system is not recognized.  Check Disk Manager to see if the card shows up there.

Comment: @WesSayeed The card still works in other laptops...and it is not just one card but 3 or 4 with different adapters. That is why I know it is a problem with the computer.

Comment: Please, tell us the HP Pavilion Slimline model, and microsd model. Card readers doesn't read all  card models. IE, HP Pavilion Slimline s3420la specs:

Reads: Compact Flash I, Compact Flash II, IBM Microdrive, Memory Stick (MS), Memory Stick Duo, Memory Stick Pro (PRO), Memory Stick Pro Duo, MultiMediaCard (MMC), MultiMediaCard Mobile (MMC mobile), MultiMediaCard Plus (MMC plus), MultiMediaCard (RS-MMC), Secure Digital (SD), Secure Digital miniSD (Mini), SmartMedia
xD Picture Card (xD). It will not read new SD standar, SDHC (SD High Capacity).

Comment: Sorry... its a Slimline s3220n. But the same cards worked before in this computer which means that surely the hardware is compatible.

Comment: **Specs for s3220n:** CompactFlash Card, MultiMediaCardmobile, MultiMediaCardplus, RS-MMC, SD Memory Card, SmartMedia Card, **microSD**, miniSD, xD-Picture Card, CompactFlash Card type I, CompactFlash Card type II, Memory Stick, Memory Stick Duo, Memory Stick PRO, Memory Stick PRO Duo, Microdrive, MultiMediaCard [See here](http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-pavilion-s3220n-slimline-athlon-64-x2-5000-plus-2-6-ghz-monitor-none-series/specs/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to find your PC model on the computer manufacturer's official website, @NULL. There you should be able to see all the available drivers & utilities. Make sure you manually update the SD card reader driver from there. 
Another thing you should try is detecting the SD card on another PC/laptop. This way you will easily find the source of the issue.

If the driver update for the SD card reader doesn't work for you, you should definitely contact the PC manufacturer's customer support for assistance. If it's still under warranty, they should be able to take care of the repair/replacement.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

*Possible Issues & Solutions:*

Some HP laptops DO NOT support SDHC cards. Use a SD-USB adapter instead.

Your SD card reader needs a driver update. (Device Manager>Right-click on SD card reader>Update Driver Software...)

Disable and Re-enable The SD card reader from Device Manager.

Your SD card port on your PC is spoilt. Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: I have tried all but the last before and multiple times :-( Could it be something in the registry? A corrupt registry entry for the hardware?

Comment: @NULL Unlikely unless you downloaded some rogue software...